# How to validate a textfield in YII before saving it to DB?

Tags: yii

How to validate a textfield in YII before saving it to DB?

I have a datepicker which I have converted it from Y-m-d format to d-m-Y format before saving.

Now, I want to validate the same field such that no date before today's date is allowed.
I have tried the following.

```
array('edate','compare','compareValue'=>date('Y-m-d'),'operator'=>'>=', 'allowEmpty'=>false),
```

Since the date is now in d-m-Y format, it is not showing an error. 
I have also tried changing the above code to
date(d-m-Y) but couldnt find the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write custom validators in Yii. So in your model file, add a function like:

```
public function isValidDate($attribute, $params)
{
    if(strtotime($this->$attribute) < time())
    {
         $this->addError($attribute, 'Date cannot be in the past');
    }
}
```

Then assign the custom validator to your attribute in the `rules()` array:

```
array('edate', 'isValidDate'),
```